# Using AWS Cognito for user management in a multi-organization application with custom permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am creating an application that has three user groups: Organisation Admin, Organisation Manager, and User.

Organisation Admin can invite Organisation Managers and Users. Organisation Managers can also define the resources that the given user group can access. For example, an Organisation Manager may not be able to create a new Organisation Manager. Since I have multiple organisations, the Organisation Manager's permissions may vary depending on the organisation they are managing.

I want to have a solution where Organisation Admin can decide on most of the endpoints in every Organisation whether the Organisation Manager has permission to perform an action or not. How can I achieve this with Cognito?"

I have created User Groups in AWS Cognito for my application, but I'm not sure how to attach custom policies to them. Specifically, I want to create policies that allow users in a group to perform certain actions such as 'query-maps', 'update-maps', and 'edit-maps'. How can I attach these custom policies to my User Groups in Cognito?